# Making a simple menu within a loop to call upon functions, stuck on why it won't work

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, menu, user-defined-functions

For a school project me and my group partner made a code, I tested each function in a separate test file to see if they worked and it all looks good, but the menu just isn't working as intended. My brain can't seem to figure out where I went wrong, I would love a second opinion on this.. thank you so much <3 Here is my code!

```
def mainmenu():
    print("Hello! Welcome to The Sprint Project Company! Please choose from 1-5: ")
    print("1. Simple IPO Program")
    print("2. IFs and Loop sample")
    print("3. Strings and dates")
    print("4. Data files and Default Values")
    print("5. Quit")


while True:
    choice = input("Enter choice (1-5): ")
    if choice == 1:
        ipo()
    elif choice == 2:
        ifloop()
    elif choice == 3:
        stringsdates()
    elif choice == 4:
        datafiles()
    else:
        break

mainmenu()
```

Whenever I run this it just automatically ends. I even tested by putting a print section under the else but it just skips straight to ending the code. Thank you so much for looking at my question <3

Comment: You would need to fix the indentation in your code to make sure the while block becomes a part of the ```mainmenu``` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points on your code.
First, the function "input()" returns a string, hence you are comparing a STRING with an INTEGER, then it evalueates to False.
It is like you are comparing 1 with '1', and they are not the same.

Second, your function mainmenu() must be put inside the loop.
Make this two changes and it will work.

```
while True:
    mainmenu()  # Add the function here.
    choice = int(input("Enter choice (1-5): "))  # Change here
    if choice == 1:
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly, you saved our project :)